# Save output of a JSON file in a Map Object Angular 6

Tags: typescript, angular6

I have a JSON file which looks like this:

```
{
"values": {"key1":"Value1", "key2":"value2"}
}
```

I have a map variable:

```
private map = new Map<string, string>();
```

How can I populate my map object with the output of this JSON file?

The method used to read JSON is:

```
this.httpClient.get('./assets/context.json').subscribe((data: any) =>  JSON.stringify(data['values']));
```

I can print output in the console but cannot save the output in a Map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using `set()` method on `Map` object

```
this.httpClient.get('./assets/context.json').subscribe(
      (data: any) => {
        Object.keys(data['values']).forEach(key => this.map.set(key, data['values'][key]))
      }
);
```

Working [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-map-object?file=src/app/app.component.ts)